# Problema de centrado vertical con CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid-layout

Pues eso, no puedo centrar verticalmente un contenido usando CSS Grid, con Flexbox no tenía problemas, estoy empezando recién con CSS Grid. Esto es lo que he intentado:

Usar el clásico método con `transform` y `translateY`:

```
.body {
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

También probé con usar un contenedor que englobe al grid así:

```
.container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Pero nada de esto me ha servido.

Lo que quiero es centrar el `div` con clase `.grid` respecto al alto del dispositivo donde se cargue la página (por ello agregué el `100vh` al `body`).

Comparto mi código:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2rem!important;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: [inicio-contenido] 1fr [fin-contenido];
  grid-template-rows: auto [inicio-contenido] auto [fin-contenido];
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 4fr [inicio-contenido] 4fr [fin-contenido];
  }
  header {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  footer {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
}

article {
  grid-column: inicio-contenido;
  grid-row: inicio-contenido;
}

header,
aside,
article,
footer {
  background: #333;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: .4rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<body>

  <div class="grid">
    <header>Header</header>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <article>
      <h1>Mi título</h1>
      <p>Contenido cool</p>
    </article>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>

</body>
```

> PD: Por alguna razón, aquí en el snippet me está tomando primero los
>   estilos de `normalize.css` y no los míos, tuve que agregar el
>   `!important` en body por este motivo.

---

Adjunto una imagen de lo que quiero lograr:
El lado A es lo que tengo actualmente, el lado B es como quiero quede, que quede centrado dependiendo del alto del navegador.

[image: Imagen de ejempplo]

Comment: Todo lo que está dentro del div con clase .grid

Comment: Gracias por tu interés @Aprendiz acabo de editar añadiendo una imagen, lo que quiero es que el contenido del `div class grid` se centre verticalmente dependiendo del alto del navegador o dispositivo donde se visualice. No me interesa centrar el texto que contenga. No tengo inconveniente con eso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considera:

- Usa grid para establecer la estructura de tu grilla
- Usar mejor flexbox para la alineación de los elementos sobre alguno de sus 2 ejes

Puedes construirlo de esta forma.

**Procedimiento**

- A la etiqueta padre del **`div`** con la clase **`grid`** es decir la etiqueta **`body`** aplicale un **`display: flex;`**, para que de este modo su nodo hijo que es el **`div`** con la clase **`grid`** se vuelva flexible y lo podamos mover sobre alguno de los ejes que componen a *flexbox*
- Eso momentaneamente moverá la maquetación de tus divs dejando todo de un extremo, del izquierdo al derecho, pues todo se acomoda sobre el *main axis*

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <style>
      body{
        margin: 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      }
      header {
        grid-column: 1/3;
        background: grey;
      }
      aside {
        grid-column: 1/2;
        background: grey;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      article {
        background: grey;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      footer {
        background: grey;
        margin-top: 10px;
        grid-column: 1/3;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
    
      <div class="grid">
        <header>Header</header>
        <aside>Aside</aside>
        <article>
          <h1>Mi título</h1>
          <p>Contenido cool</p>
        </article>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
      </div>
    
    </body>
```

Nota: *Prueba este código en algún sistema como **JS Fiddle** para que puedas ver mejor su funcionamiento*

Agrego el snnipet con el [ejemplo](https://jsbin.com/fimofiroqe/edit?html,output)

Comment: Lo siento pero no funciona, lo veo igual, pegado a la parte superior. Podrías agregar un snippet por favor? A lo mejor me estoy perdiendo algo.

Comment: Tuve que mover un poco mi código pero al final pude lograrlo con su ayuda. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a poner un centrado vertical a la etiqueta del contenedor en concreto a través de CSS:

```
.centrado {vertical-align: middle;display:inline;}

<div class="grid">
<header>Header</header>
<aside>Aside</aside>
<article>
<div class="centrado">
<h1>Mi título</h1>
<p>Contenido cool</p>
</div>
</article>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, ya intenté hacerlo, pero al ser un sistema con CSS Grid se complica la implementación.

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaración y disculpa porque mi respuesta no ayuda a tu consulta, al leearla rápido no entendí cortrectamente la necesidad de tu código, siento no haberte podido ayudar. No obstante el compañero que responde arriba te da un muy buena ayuda. Lamento la confunsión.

Comment: Gracias a usted por su tiempo. Un saludo!